# ¿Como crear un contador de visitas? Con gráficas representativas

Tags: php, javascript

Vera tengo un código que no resuelvo del todo bien, y quiero crear una gráfica con datos representativos de x Usuarios Online, x Usuarios Offline, Total de visitas, Total de Usuarios Únicos, y visitas mas recientes. Pero me quede atracando en usuarios online y Offline, y visitas recientes.
Como podría lograrlo?

Este es mi gráfica:

[image]
Este es mi código php, con el cual creo un campo en mi base de datos y la actualizo:

```
<?php
require_once "conn.php";
session_start();
$_SESSSION['id'] = (isset($_SESSION['id'])) ? $_SESSION['id'] : $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
 $_SESSION['time'] = time();
 function checkPageName($page){
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".HITS." WHERE page = :page";
$query = $GLOBALS['db']->prepare($sql);
$query->execute([':page' => $page]);
if ($query->rowCount() == 0){
$sql = "INSERT INTO ".HITS." (page, count) VALUES (:page, 0)";
$query = $GLOBALS['db']->prepare($sql);
$query->execute([':page' => $page]);
}
}
function updateCounter($page){
checkPageName($page);
$sql = "UPDATE ".HITS." SET count = count+1 WHERE page = :page";
$query = $GLOBALS['db']->prepare($sql);
$query->execute([':page' => $page]);
}
function updateInfo($ip){
$sql = "INSERT INTO ".INFO." (ip, status, count, user_agent) VALUES(:ip, :status, :count, :user_agent)";
$query = $GLOBALS['db']->prepare($sql);
$query->execute([
':ip' => $ip,
':status' => 1,
':count' => 0,
':user_agent' => $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]
]);
}
function updateIPCount($ip) {
if ($_SESSION['time'] < time() - 60) {
session_destroy();
$sql = "UPDATE ".INFO." SET status = 0 WHERE ip = :ip";
}else{
$sql = "UPDATE ".INFO." SET status = 1, count = count+1, time = NOW(), user_agent = :user_agent WHERE ip = :ip";
}
$query = $GLOBALS['db']->prepare($sql);
$query->execute([
':ip' => $ip,
':user_agent' => $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]
]);
}
function checkIP($ip){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".INFO." WHERE ip = :ip";
$query = $GLOBALS['db']->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':ip', $ip);
$query->execute();
if ($query->rowCount() > 0){
updateIPCount($ip);
}else{
updateInfo($ip);
}
}
updateCounter("MyWeb");
checkIP($id);
?>
```

En mi base de datos, tengo 2 tablas, una con la información del titulo de la pagina y el total de visitas. Y la otra con la información de cada usuario, ip, agente de usuario, fecha de la ultima conexión, veces en las que se ha conectado y el estado ya sea online o offline.
Esta el a estructura de mis tales:

```
Tabla Hits
 id: auto_increment
 page_name: MyPage
 count: 100
 recent: 10

 Tabla Info
  id: auto_increment
  count: 30
  estatus: 1 // 1 online / 0 offline
  ip: 123.456.789
  user_agent: Mozilla
  date: 2017-07-27 00:00:00
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66252/discussion-on-question-by-eddy-otsutsuki-como-crear-un-contador-de-visitas-con).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal y como tienes planteado el código y las tablas será difícil obtener la información que solicitas (y mantenerla actualizada).

Partiremos de las siguientes definiciones:

- Total de visitas: número de "clics" totales en una página.
- Usuarios únicos: número de sesiones nuevas creadas.
- Usuarios online: número de usuarios que han tenido actividad en una página en los últimos 30 minutos.
- Usuarios offline: número de usuarios que han tenido una visita a la página durante las últimas 24 horas pero no han mostrado actividad los últimos 30 minutos.
- Visitas más recientes: número de "clics" durante las últimas 24 horas.

Trabajaremos con dos tablas, una para el registro de actividad de las últimas 24 horas y otra para el registro de actividad total.

Tabla `actividad`:

- id (opcional)
- pagina
- uniqid
- timestamp
- índice: pagina + timestamp

Tabla `total`:

- id (opcional)
- pagina
- usuarios
- visitas

Para gestionar la tabla `total` basta agregar este código al comienzo del script:

```
<?php
/* NOTA: No necesitamos el soporte de sesiones de PHP para nada */
/* Comprobamos si es un usuario recurrente o nuevo mediante su cookie */
if (false === isset($_COOKIE['registrado'])) {
  /* Agregamos un nuevo usuario y visita a la cuenta */
  /* UPDATE total
     SET usuarios = usuarios + 1, visitas = visitas + 1
     WHERE pagina = :pagina */
  $_COOKIE['registrado'] = uniqid('', true);
  /* Creamos una cookie que dure un año */
  setcookie(
    'registrado',
    $_COOKIE['registrado'],
    time() + 31536000 /* 365 x 24 x 60 x 60 */
  );
} else {
  /* Agregamos únicamente una visita a la cuenta */
  /* UPDATE total
     SET visitas = visitas + 1
     WHERE pagina = :pagina */
}
/* Registramos la actividad */
/* INSERT INTO actividad (
     pagina,
     uniqid,
     timestamp
   ) VALUES (
     :pagina,
     :uniqid,
     NOW()
   ) */
/* ... trabajo realizado ... */
```

Ahora las consultas que necesitas realizar para obtener los datos:

### Total de visitas y usuarios únicos

```
SELECT
  visitas,
  usuarios
FROM total
WHERE pagina = :pagina
```

### Visitas más recientes

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) recientes
FROM actividad
WHERE
  pagina = :pagina
AND
  timestamp > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
```

### Usuarios online

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT uniqid) online
FROM actividad
WHERE
  pagina = :pagina
AND
  timestamp > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
```

### Usuarios offline

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT uniqid) ultimas24h
FROM actividad
WHERE
  pagina = :pagina
AND
  timestamp > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
```

Al valor del total de conectados las últimas 24 horas le restaríamos el valor de los conectados durante los últimos 30 minutos.

Comment: Funciona excelentemente, gracias por tanta paciencia. :)

Comment: De nada, me alegra haber sido de ayuda.